# How to enable optical/LED notifications on Android 9/Fairphone 3?

Tags: notifications, 9.0-pie, notification-led, fairphone-3

I'm used to the LED indicator light on the front for unseen notifications from Moto G2014/LineageOS 14. I searched for 10 minutes for a setting and I think I revisited all of them. There is however a LED in the front which indicates the charging progress. I assume it can be used for notifications as well.

There're a few forum post which claim to explain how to enable it, but don't.

The Fairphone has Android 9, updated yesterday.

Comment: This seems to be a [known bug](https://forum.fairphone.com/t/led-notifications-do-not-work/53013) of the Fairphone 3.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the link. Is there a bug report where developers work on? It's in general impossible to retrieve any information from forum posts. I'd accept it as an answer. If there's none you can post the link to the forum post as well as an answer.